# folder structure in xcode vs folder structure in finder

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have the following folder structure in xcode for a project.

[image: file structure in xcode]

[image: file structure in finder]

However, I have the above file structure in finder.
Is there any way to reflect the file structure from xcode to finder ?

Comment: You should mark Corneliu's answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 47):

I recently discovered a **Command Line Tool** that will do exactly what you need. You can find it here:

https://github.com/venmo/synx

To install the tool, you just need to open the terminal and run the following command (use **sudo** to run it as a superuser and get permission):

```
$ sudo gem install synx
```

Then, just like the instructions on the GitHub webpage above indicate, use the following command to re-organize your folder structure:

```
$ synx path/to/your/project.xcodeproj
```

This should do it :).

Comment: Thank you so much!! If you're ever in Houston, let me know so I can buy you a beer.

Comment: After I do this, it says current file is missing from working copy. Which setting I need to change to make xcode aware of the folder changes.

Answer (score 4):

You should managed it yourself in Finder, then set new Path for folders in Utility View
[image: Xcode folder path]

Answer (score 3):

The "folders" in Xcode are actually groups and not necessarily linked to a folder in Finder.

You need to manage it yourself if you want a mirror in Xcode/Finder.

What you can do is create the folder structure you desire in Finder, then drag each folder into Xcode, this will create references to the folders as groups in Xcode and any files you create in those groups will be saved in the appropriate Finder folders.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do this to some extent! There's just one extra step to do every time you create a new group (and this first time you'll have a lot of catching up to do!):

- **Xcode 3:** Whenever you create a group in Xcode, immediately get info on it, and notice the "Path:" setting just below its name. Click "Choose..." and set it to a new folder with the same name.
- **Xcode 4:** Whenever you create a group in Xcode, immediately select it and open the righthand sidebar. Notice the "Path:" setting just below its name. Click the icon next to "None" (what is that, a file in a window?) and set it to a new folder with the same name.

Now, whenever you add files to the group, they'll head to the corresponding folder on disk. Woo!

**Hence**, I always create folder in Finder and then add that in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

After version 9 Xcode (haven't checked previous versions) handles this for you! As long as you create a group and you don't select "New group without folder" Xcode automagically creates a corresponding folder in your project that will be reflected in your project's file structure.